# Adding SOAP securityHeader | ws:outbound-gateway

Tags: soap, spring-integration, ws-security

Currently I have a wsgateway which invokes a outbound SOAP service. Now the provider wants to add security header to the outgoing SOAP message.

I need to include below as part of the SOAP:Header in order to get the service call successful.

```
<wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1"
            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
                <wsse:Username>xxxx</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password  Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">xxxx</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
```

How to use Header enricher or mapper to solve this. 
Current Implementation:

```
<int:chain input-channel="doOutBoundCallNow" output-channel="printChannel">
            <ws:outbound-gateway uri="http://localhost:8082/mockBinding"></ws:outbound-gateway>



</int:chain>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked to the Spring WS [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/security.html#security-wss4j-security-interceptor) ?

You should configure `Wss4jSecurityInterceptor` for the `WSHandlerConstants.USERNAME_TOKEN` and add this `interceptor` to the `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>`.

Comment: I am using 2.2.2.RELEASE version of spring-ws. What version of wss4j I should use?

Comment: Not sure, but I'd just follow with the Spring WS dependency: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/blob/master/build.gradle#L247

Comment: After upgrading the wss4j to 1.6.4 the issue related to setting "UsernameToken" action was resolved.

Comment: org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: SOAP Envelope can not have children other than SOAP Header and Body

This exception is thrown now.

Comment: Share the StackTrace, please, in your question together with the configuration for the `Wss4jSecurityInterceptor` and `<int-ws:outbound-gateway>`.